# Evaluate Integral over a line segemnt

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Evaluate $$\int_{[\alpha , \beta]} Rz \, dz$$
where $[\alpha , \beta]$ denotes the line segment joining $\alpha$ to $\beta$.

I feel like this should be easier than im making it but there is not really a function to integrate here. we are just given $Rz$ and I am unclear on what that specifically means.

Comment: Is that the real part of $z$?

Comment: It is unclear if you mean a constant multiple of $z$ (like $R\cdot z$) or the real part of $z$ (like $\operatorname{Re}z$).

Comment: It could be $\frac{R}{2} (\beta^2 - \alpha^2)$

Comment: @user251257 Yes it is the real part of z

Comment: @MPW Yes it is the real part of z

Comment: $\text {Re } z$ is certainly a function of $z$.

Comment: A one-to-one parametrization of the segement is given by $g:[0,1]\ni t\mapsto\alpha (1-t) + \beta t$. Does this help?